# Detecting focus loss in fullscreen mode in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, focus, fullscreen

I'm making a HTML5 application that must be run in fullscreen mode. When the user leaves fullscreen or switches to another window in multi-monitor set-up, the app must receive a notification and pause.

I have created a timeout that constantly checks if the browser has focus and the fullscreen is on:

```
function check() {
    // detect state
    var isFullscreen = $(document).fullScreen();
    var isFocused = document.hasFocus();

    // force user out of fullscreen if focus is lost
    if(isFullscreen && !isFocused) {
        isFullscreen = false;
        $(document).fullScreen(false);
    }

    if(!isFullscreen) {
        pause();
    } else {
        unpause();
    }
}

setInterval(check, 200);
```

This code works perfectly in Chrome and IE. All browsers display a confirmation window above the page.

However, only in Firefox, clicking the "Confirm" button in this window makes the browser lose focus! The `check` function immediately detects it and forces the user out of fullscreen, rendering the application unusable.

Is there any known workaround for this issue?

Comment: `$(document).fullScreen();` are you using jQuery or a plugin ? is it HTML5 ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day, I'm using the jQuery Fullscreen plugin from here: https://plugins.jquery.com/fullscreen/

Comment: `clicking the "Confirm" button` wich button are you talking about ? there is no button in your code ? is that related to the browser confirmation ?

Comment: @Anonymous0day, yes, I mean the built-in notification that all browsers display when fullscreen mode is activated. It is not in my code.